# Как использовать findOne в mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
Есть код на сервере, который проверяет наличие в базе emailа и пароля. findOne в консоли выводит:
```

Cursor {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: true,
    highWaterMark: 16,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: null,
    pipesCount: 0,
    flowing: null,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    sync: true,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: false,
    destroyed: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrain: 0,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
  },

и ещё кучу обьектов. Как получить true или false от findOne и возможно ли так сделать?

```js
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    let email = req.body.registrationEmail;
    let password = req.body.registrationPassword;

    mongoClient.connect(function (err, client) {
        const db = client.db("site");
        const collection = db.collection("users");

        let user = {email: email, password: password};
        console.dir(user);
        console.dir(collection.find({email:user.email,password:user.password}));
        collection.findOne({user}),function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.dir("ошибка");
                res.send(`{"email":"${user.email}"}`);
            } else {
                res.redirect('/');
            }
        };
        console.dir(req.body);
    });
});
```

Comment: Вы хотите узнать есть ли документ с определенным email, но сам документ Вам не нужен? Используйте `collection.count` - в ответ получите число

Comment: @Дмытрык, Вот что выводит с сollection.count: Promise { <pending> }. Попробую then добавить

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря подсказке @Yaant, решил проблему через find. Может пригодится кому-нибудь для проверки по базе.

```js
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    let email = req.body.registrationEmail;
    let password = req.body.registrationPassword;

    mongoClient.connect(function (err, client) {
        const db = client.db("site");
        const collection = db.collection("users");
        db.collection('users').find({"email": email, "password":password}).count()
            .then(function (numItems) {
                console.log(numItems);
                if (numItems === 0) {
                    res.send(`{"email":"${email}"}`);
                } else {
                    res.redirect('/');
                }
            })
            .catch(function (numItems) {
                res.send(`{"email":"${email}"}`);
                console.log('error');
            });

    });
});
```

Comment: Вроде, можно сразу "db.collection('users').count({"email": email, "password":password})" вызывать (или countDocuments - у них нововведение, count стал deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать await, если используется async/await. Например так(User это модель mongoose):

```
const userCandidate = await User.findOne({ email });

if (userCandidate) {
  throw new Error(`пользователь с email ${email} уже существует`);
}
```